# Two-way recording with twilio SIP

Tags: twilio, sip, call-recording

I have set-up a SIP Domain on twilio and I've configured with the following TwinML :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial callerId="{{#e164}}{{From}}{{/e164}}">
    {{#e164}}{{To}}{{/e164}}
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

I would like to record all inbound and outbound calls coming on this number but it fails.

I have tried this code :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial callerId="{{#e164}}{{From}}{{/e164}}">
    {{#e164}}{{To}}{{/e164}}
  </Dial>
  
  
  <Dial record="record-from-ringing-dual"
   recordingStatusCallback="https://sample.org/api/1.1/wf/twiliocalllog"
>
 <Number>+339999999</Number>
 </Dial>
</Response>
```

Can you tell me how can I handle this issue?

(For Inbound calls, I did it with Studio and it works properly, but for outbound calls, I can't find the best way).

Answer (score 0):

For the outbound call you need to use the `record` attribute on the `<Dial>` that places the call. Like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial callerId="{{#e164}}{{From}}{{/e164}}" record="record-from-ringing-dual" recordingStatusCallback="https://sample.org/api/1.1/wf/twiliocalllog">
    {{#e164}}{{To}}{{/e164}}
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer. Do you have an idea how to catch the caller informations because I'm receiving the recordingstatuscallback but it does not contain any information about the call (from, to)?

Comment: The [webhook to the `recordingStatusCallback` URL includes the `CallSid`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording#recordingstatuscallback) and you can use that to [fetch the rest of the information about the call from the API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#fetch-a-call-resource).